# When should I use object property shorthand?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, properties, key, shorthand

I understand it's used when the object keys and values are the same (i.e., `cat: cat` can just be rewritten as `cat`)...but when I look at code examples, I get confused as to *which situations* have their keys and values equal to each other.

```js
let cat = 'Miaow';
let dog = 'Woof';
let bird = 'Peet peet';

let someObject = {
  cat,
  dog,
  bird
}

console.log(someObject);
```

Comment: please add an example. i see no object.

Comment: There are no exact situations when the key and value would be the same. It's your data, **if** you deem it appropriate for your data, then that is the situation.

Comment: Here's an example of the key and value being the same: https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/

Comment: can you please tell me why they deemed the key and value to be the same in the object?

Comment: maybe you have a look here: [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: Shorthand looks cleaner, but in my experience it seems to confuse developers newer to javascript, who have a hard time distinguishing between the name of the constant you're placing as the value of the object property, and the name of the object property itself. Especially in function returns. I'm not sure it's actually a beneficial feature.

Answer (score 2):

From the Docs:

> ### New notations in ECMAScript 2015 <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)</sup>
>
> In non-supporting environments, these notations will lead to syntax errors.
>
> ```
> // Shorthand property names (ES2015)
> let a = 'foo', b = 42, c = {};
> let o = {a, b, c}
>
> // Shorthand method names (ES2015)
> let o = {
>   property(parameters) {}
> }
>
> // Computed property names (ES2015)
> let prop = 'foo'
> let o = {
>   [prop]: 'hey',
>   ['b' + 'ar']: 'there'
> }
> ```

These notations will not work with Internet Explorer.

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Object Initializer - New notations in ECMAScript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Object Initializer - Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility)